# DOJO and AJAX using with Struts2

Tags: jquery, ajax, dojo, struts2

Is there a strong CRUD application/tutorial using DOJO and/or AJAX in Struts2?

I mean using standard Struts2 DOJO taglib:

> <%@taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags" %>

and jQuery taglib:

> <%@taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags" %>

not classic AJAX, I think it's more efficient to develop and to maintain.

I already looked in http://struts.apache.org/ , but there are only two very weak tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JQuery plugin wiki pages have a number of examples, but no complete CRUD tutorial.

Other than the [S2/JPA/Ajax](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/struts-2-spring-2-jpa-ajax.html) tutorial there isn't any "official" S2 tutorial.

In general, once whichever Ajax tags are understood there isn't much more to add, though.

I'm sure you already know, but just in case: the Dojo tags are deprecated, cranky, and use an ancient version of Dojo (0.4.3) and will likely never be updated.

All this said, for all but the simplest of usecases, I'm not convinced that a JavaScript/Ajax tag library is really the way to go, particularly in today's Unobtrusive JavaScript world.

Comment: If today were Unobstrusive Javascript world I wouldn't need so many exceptions on my Noscript...

Comment: Until now I use classic jQuery library for making AJAX calls, but I wanted to give a try with standard Struts2 library, maybe it could help me in some ways to work much faster on biggest projects

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reference available. The tag reference also speaks about dojo with ajax usage.

http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/ajax-tags.html